# Symfony + Docker deployment, not creating .env file

Tags: php, docker, symfony, dockerfile, render.com

I don't know how to put it but I'll try my best to make it clear. I'm deploying my first app using symfony, docker ang nginx on render.com. Deployment seemed fine but page was blank so I looked into logs and had `"Unable to read "var/www/html.env""` so I guess `.env` is missing. When I deleted `.env` from `.dockerignore`, app is working totaly fine but I think database URL shouldn't be public inside my public github repo. 
I tried using render.com built in Environment Variables but when I once again put `.env` file into `.dockerignore` error occurs. So is there a way to hendle secrets with Dockerfile? My solution was to create another private repository on github and add my DB URL, remove .env from .dockerignore and upload to render webapp, it's working but not sure if I'm doing the right thing.

Comment: if you use docker - dont create an .env file, give the docker container the env variables it needs directly. (best via docker-compose.yml)

Answer (score 0):

Symfony Dotenv library supports .env files hierarchies.

The common practice is to have basic .env file in source control system (i.e. not git- or docker- ignored) which contains only the names of used variables, or maybe some reasonable defaults, which should not be secured. And another file .env.local is loaded after that. It overrides values from .env file and it should be git- (or docker-, in your case) ignored, and contain secure values.

In production, you can either create its own .env.local file where to define secrets, OR define real env vars, as shown here [render.com env var docs](https://render.com/docs/configure-environment-variables)

Seems like your error returned back because symfony/dotenv relies on the existence of .env file. So I suggest remove all the secrets from this file to the .env.local counterparts and add it to the docker image. Then error should go away.